# DataTable not a function at rootRef.on.Snap

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, datatables, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the following errors when I run my website.I think there is something wrong the way I am entering data in my dataTable columns.I have provided an image below of my firebase database.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at rootRef.on.snap
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Orders/");
    rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
        console.log(snap.val());

        var snapper = snap.val();

        $('example').DataTable({
            "ajax": "snapper",
            "columns": [{
                    "Orders": "User id"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Email"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Address"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Dabba Type"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Session"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Start Date"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "End Date"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Phone no"
                },
                {
                    "Orders": "Total Price"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

This is image which shows how my Firebase database is structured:

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you have Datatable.js included on page? I think that's what is missed

Comment: Yes I have included it.

Comment: Can you confirm that your script is included **after** Datatable.js?

Comment: `$('example')` is not an element. if it's the id selector, it should be `$('#example')`.. Note the **#**

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal it's not that, even if the selector doesn't have any element in the DOM, this function will return a jQuery object. It seems to be what you said first.

Comment: I have put the # but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Console log out $('example').DataTable to see what it is. Ideally, open up Chrome Dev Tools and put a breakpoint on that line, then open the Dev Tools console so you can debug it live.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/ojas/Desktop/MumbaiDabbawalaWeb/public/mumbaidabbawala.json?_=1489684491968. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4